# c# database Select then insert. But the value is 0

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database

I am trying to select then insert a datetime from Table 1 to Table 2. I have successfully insert the data. However, the datetime shown in Table 2 is 0000-00-00 00:00:00. Idk where is the error. Someone please help me with this problem. I am struggling with this. And is this the correct way to SELECT then insert ? (Select from Table 1 then INSERT into Table 2)

```
 try
    {
        string myConnectionString;
        myConnectionString= "server=localhost;uid=root;pwd=root;database=medicloud;SslMode=None;charset=utf8";

        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString);
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        EncodingProvider ppp;
        ppp = CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance;
        Encoding.RegisterProvider(ppp);

        connection.Open();   

        string select = "Select time from assign where userId=@name";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtValue.Text);                           
        cmd.CommandText = select;
        cmd.Connection = connection;


        MySqlDataReader selectAssign = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        selectAssign.Read();
        string assign = (selectAssign["time"].ToString());
        selectAssign.Close();


        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT into bluetooth (userId,arm,armNumberDone,armNumber,comDate,assignDate,status) VALUES (@name, @stupid0, @stupid1, @stupid2, @stupid3, @stupid4, @stupid5)";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stupid0", databaseLine);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stupid1", counter);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stupid2", databaseValue);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stupid3", DateTime.Now);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stupid4", assign);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stupid5", complete);
        cmd.Connection = connection;


        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();

    }

    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        txtExercise.Text = ex.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Why is `assign` a `string` rather than `DateTime`?

Comment: Probably not a solution but: https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: after `string assign = (selectAssign["time"].ToString());`, what is the value of the variable `assign`? Have you added a breakpoint to check?

Comment: I have not check yet . I will check it now

Comment: I can run my debugging now. But when I added a break point at the "string assign" line, and I press F11. The toggle breakpoint moves down. Is this normal ?

Comment: @AndyRefuerzo Okay I did it. When I mouse over the "assign" it says, assign|null

Comment: It means you are not getting any values back that is why you are inserting `0000-00-00 00:00:00` value. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with this

```
try
{
      string myConnectionString;
      myConnectionString = "server=localhost;uid=root;pwd=root;database=medicloud;SslMode=None;charset=utf8";

      MySqlConnection connection = new 
           MySqlConnection(myConnectionString);
      MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();

      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

      EncodingProvider ppp;
      ppp = CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance;
      Encoding.RegisterProvider(ppp);

      connection.Open();

      string select = "Select time from assign where userId=@name";
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtValue.Text);
      cmd.CommandText = select;
      cmd.Connection = connection;

      MySqlDataReader selectAssign = cmd.ExecuteReader();
      selectAssign.Read();
      string assign = (selectAssign["time"].ToString());
      selectAssign.Close();

      DateTime assignDate = DateTime.Now;
      DateTime.TryParseExact(assign, out assignDate);

      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
      cmd.CommandText = "INSERT into bluetooth 
(userId,arm,armNumberDone,armNumber,comDate,assignDate,status) VALUES (@name, 
@stupid0, @stupid1, @stupid2, @stupid3, @stupid4, @stupid5)";
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stupid0", databaseLine);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stupid1", counter);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stupid2", databaseValue);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stupid3", DateTime.Now);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stupid4", assignDate);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stupid5", complete);
      cmd.Connection = connection;

      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      connection.Close();
   }
  catch (MySqlException ex)
  {
      txtExercise.Text = ex.ToString();
  }
}
```

Comment: It has an error on TryParseExact. IT says "No overload for method 'TryParseExact' takes 2 arguments"

Comment: OMG IT WORKED. I changed to "TryParse" instead and it worked beautifully :) Thanks for the help

Comment: Some additional tips: MySqlConnection, MySqlCommand and MySqlDataReader are all IDisposable, so should all be in `using` blocks. Also, take a look at [can we stop using AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stupid3", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stupid4", GetDateString(assign));
```

Have a method like this:

```
public static string GetDateString(string date)
{
    DateTime theDate;
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", 
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out theDate))
    {
        // the string was successfully parsed into theDate
        return theDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    }
    else
    {
        // the parsing failed, return some sensible default value
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.ExecuteReader()` the use `.Read()` to move to each row in the result set. If you are sure the exactly one row will be returned, use `.ExecuteScalar()` instead. Research on the difference of both online. Below is an example using `.ExecuteReader()`.

I also re-wrote to use `using` statements to simplify a bit but not deviate too much from your original code so you do not need to worry about closing and disposing resources since they inherit from `IDisposable` and will do that automatically once they exit the `using` block:

```
string assign = DateTime.Now.ToString();

string myConnectionString;
    myConnectionString= "server=localhost;uid=root;pwd=root;database=medicloud;SslMode=None;charset=utf8";

string select = "Select time from assign where userId=@name";

using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString))
{
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(select))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = con;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtValue.Text);                      

        using (MySqlDataReader cursor = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (cursor.Read())
            {
                assign = cursor["time"];
            }
        }
    }

    string insert = "INSERT into bluetooth (userId,arm,armNumberDone,armNumber,comDate,assignDate,status) VALUES (@name, @stupid0, @stupid1, @stupid2, @stupid3, @stupid4, @stupid5)";

    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(insert))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = con;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stupid0", databaseLine);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stupid1", counter);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stupid2", databaseValue);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stupid3", DateTime.Now);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stupid4", assign);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stupid5", complete);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Should your line be "string assign = DateTime.Now.ToString();" ?

Comment: It still displays 0000-00-00 00:00:00 though :(